# TSQL To Search For Only Specific Chars In Any Position

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

Have alphanumeric in an nvarchar

Want to search for only 
-0-9 
(-0123456789)

```
select top 1000 id, word
from FTSwordDef with (nolock) 
where word like '[-0-9]%'
```

Will return -0-9 in the first position.

Want to apply -0-9 to all positions

So -123c would fail as c is not -0-9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WHERE word NOT LIKE '%[^0-9-]%';
```

You can also say:

```
WHERE PATINDEX('%[^0-9-]%', word) = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

do you have the option to install a regex UDF? If so you can do this by regular expression

Comment: RegEx is probably overkill for this purpose.